# How can accessing a strong member variable result in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash on the line:

```
[self.serviceChannel suspend];
```

where `serviceChannel` is declared as so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PNServiceChannel *serviceChannel;
```

I am using ARC.  How is this possible?  My understanding is that ARC should prevent this.  What am I missing here?

Comment: If you break on the crashing line and execute `po self.serviceChannel` do you get a description of an instance of `PNServiceChannel`?  Is it possible that `self.serviceChannel` is fine, but you're crashing inside the `suspend` method?

Comment: It may happen under unfortunate circumstances. For example there is somehow `self` released and it's a zombie object (yes, it can happen even when using ARC). Run `Instruments` in zombie mode.

Answer (score 0):

serviceChannel is strong so self will not release it. But maybe self has been released or you are crashing inside suspend. Put a breakpoint in the beginning of suspend method. If the breakpoint is reached, the crash must happen in suspend and you should debug that. If it is not reached, then self must be released before the call.